# Do the maintainers of JavaScript remove features?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

Really dumb question. I really like the new feature called "optional chaining" in JavaScript, and it's used in quite a few places in my front end code. However, I am concerned that whoever maintains JavaScript, maybe Mozilla Foundation, will remove this feature in the future, and my code will be broken. Is that likely? Or, it might remove some other features that I use in my code that is so popular.

Comment: Recommended read: [Martian Headsets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/03/17/martian-headsets/) by Joel Spolsky.

Comment: If whoever maintains JavaScript breaks everyone's websites, browsers will ignore the JavaScript maintainers. Because if browsers break everyone's websites, people don't use those browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, the [ECMAScript standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) is standardized by [Ecma International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecma_International), not the Mozilla Foundation. You see the Mozilla Foundation (makers of FireFox) come up a lot (e.g. in search results) because their MDN docs are quite excellent.

> ECMAScript (/ˈɛkməskrɪpt/; ES)[1] is a JavaScript standard intended to ensure the interoperability of web pages across different browsers.[2] It is standardized by Ecma International in the document ECMA-262.

As for whether or not JavaScript features will be removed in the future: it's entirely *possible*, but avoided at pretty much all costs. The people running the show understand that JS power the web, and there's decades of software out there that will never be rewritten or even patched, and they don't want to break compatibility with it. For example, strict mode was introduced as an opt-in feature, preserving the default non-strict behaviour so existing programs can still work.

Comment: It might interest. [ECMA-262 Proposals](https://github.com/tc39/proposals). When you are quite exposed to a stack (even JS), roadmaps can be your friend. This list of proposals might or might not be a roadmap as such, but still.